# Xwiki - Error with Apostrophe in Space Title or Page Title

Tags: xwiki

I have installed a fresh install of XWiki on a Windows platform.

The XWiki instance was installed using hsql for data storage.

The XWiki instance is hosted on Apache Tomcat.

Some of my users entered an apostrophe into the title of a page as well as the page content.

I received the following error:
http://jira.xwiki.org/jira/browse/XE-767

What is my next step to fix my broken XWiki instance?
Is there a way to upgrade a XWiki instance to a version that works?  How do I save my existing content?
From reviewing the developers comments, it appears that issue has been corrected.

I, however, do not have enough background in Java or XWiki to know how I can move forward.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the best solution is to upgrade to a newer version. Don't worry, upgrades are not that difficult.

http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/AdminGuide/Installation#HUpgradinganXWikiInstallation

There are two parts in an upgrade: the platform, meaning all the files on the filesystem, and the wiki content, since quite often things change in the default wiki documents. Your specific bug can be fixed by upgrading the platform part, so if you're not too confident about upgrading the wiki content, you can just leave the old content in place.

In order not to lose your current database, be sure to leave the old "database" folder in place, and just replace the "webapps\xwiki" part.

Comment: General comment on process:  I really enjoy XWiki as a product.   For others who support the product, the following process more helpful: (0) Export content from current Xwiki install.  (1) Install a fresh install of XWiki.  (2) Install base XWiki content.   (3) Import the data from step zero.  Thanks for the pointer in the right direction.

Comment: It seems that you comment on many forums regarding XWiki.   I really appreciate your comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

From the error report the versions that fix the issue are

- 2.7 - http://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/ReleaseNotes/ReleaseNotesXWikiEnterprise27
- 2.6.1 - http://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/ReleaseNotes/ReleaseNotesXWikiEnterprise261

You can upgrade to one of them or to any following version, like XE

- 3.0 - http://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/ReleaseNotes/ReleaseNotesXWikiEnterprise30

All versions can be downloaded from http://forge.ow2.org/project/showfiles.php?group_id=170

In a project that has such a rapid development cycle is very good to upgrade often in order to benefit from the latest features and bug fixes.